# Missing concrete implementation of statelessWidget.build

Tags: flutter

I am getting this error in Dart: "Missing concrete implementation of "stateless-Widget.build".
Does anyone knows what this error means and
how to solve it?
What can I do to prevent the compiler from throwing the
following warning on the following code?is this because of getter method that i used
because of that two errors also occured

```
 child: Image.network(
                    imageUrl,         //undefined name imageUrl
                    height: 250,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),

child: Text(
                      title,                         //undefined name title
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 26,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      softWrap: true,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                    ),
```

Code:

```
import 'package:dishes_app/models/meal.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MealItem extends StatelessWidget {     //error
  final String title;
  final String imageUrl;
  final int duration;
  final Complexity complexity;
  final Affordability affordability;

  MealItem({
    required this.title,
    required this.imageUrl,
    required this.duration,
    required this.complexity,
    required this.affordability,
  });



  String get complexityText {
    switch (complexity) {
      case Complexity.Simple:
        return 'Simple';
        break;
      case Complexity.Challenging:
        return 'Challenging';
        break;
      case Complexity.Hard:
        return 'Hard';
        break;
      default:
        return 'Unknown';
    }
  }
    String get affordabilityText {
    switch (affordability) {
      case Affordability.Affordable:
        return 'Affordable';
        break;
      case Affordability.Pricey:
        return 'Pricey';
        break;
      case Affordability.Luxurious:
        return 'Expensive';
        break;
      default:
        return 'Unknown';
    }
  }


  
  }

  void selectmeal() {}

  
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: selectmeal,
      child: Card(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
        elevation: 4,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Stack(
              children: [
                ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(15),
                  ),
                  child: Image.network(
                    imageUrl,
                    height: 250,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 20,
                  right: 20,
                  child: Container(
                    width: 300,
                    color: Colors.black54,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 20),
                    child: Text(
                      title,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 26,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      softWrap: true,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Icon(Icons.schedule),
                      SizedBox(width: 6),
                      Text('$duration min'),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Icon(Icons.work),
                      SizedBox(width: 6),
                      Text('complexityText'),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Icon(Icons.attach_money),
                      SizedBox(width: 6),
                      Text('affordabilityText'),
                    ],
                  ),
                  
                ],
                
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just closed the MealItem before `override` the build method. Just remove the close curly braces or try the below code supports.

```
class MealItem extends StatelessWidget {
  //error
  final String title;
  final String imageUrl;
  final int duration;
  final Complexity complexity;
  final Affordability affordability;

  MealItem({
    required this.title,
    required this.imageUrl,
    required this.duration,
    required this.complexity,
    required this.affordability,
  });

  String get complexityText {
    switch (complexity) {
      case Complexity.Simple:
        return 'Simple';
        break;
      case Complexity.Challenging:
        return 'Challenging';
        break;
      case Complexity.Hard:
        return 'Hard';
        break;
      default:
        return 'Unknown';
    }
  }

  String get affordabilityText {
    switch (affordability) {
      case Affordability.Affordable:
        return 'Affordable';
        break;
      case Affordability.Pricey:
        return 'Pricey';
        break;
      case Affordability.Luxurious:
        return 'Expensive';
        break;
      default:
        return 'Unknown';
    }
  }

  void selectmeal() {}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: selectmeal,
      child: Card(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
        elevation: 4,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Stack(
              children: [
                ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(15),
                  ),
                  child: Image.network(
                    imageUrl,
                    height: 250,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 20,
                  right: 20,
                  child: Container(
                    width: 300,
                    color: Colors.black54,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 20),
                    child: Text(
                      title,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 26,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      softWrap: true,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Icon(Icons.schedule),
                      SizedBox(width: 6),
                      Text('$duration min'),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Icon(Icons.work),
                      SizedBox(width: 6),
                      Text('complexityText'),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Icon(Icons.attach_money),
                      SizedBox(width: 6),
                      Text('affordabilityText'),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a spare } here

```
    String get affordabilityText {
    switch (affordability) {
      case Affordability.Affordable:
        return 'Affordable';
        break;
      case Affordability.Pricey:
        return 'Pricey';
        break;
      case Affordability.Luxurious:
        return 'Expensive';
        break;
      default:
        return 'Unknown';
    }
  }


  
 }//HERE
```